# Magento Product Grid 'Cost Price' 3 decimal place

Tags: grid, product-grid

I want 3 decimal places for "cost" like the "Price"

app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

```
        $store = $this->_getStore();
    $this->addColumn('cost',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Cost'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
            'index' => 'cost',
    ));


    $this->addColumn('price',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
            'type'  => 'price',
            'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
            'index' => 'price',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('special_price',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Special Price'),
        'type'  => 'price',
        'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
        'index' => 'special_price',
    ));
```

[image: Magento cost price]

if anyone can help me in this...

Comment: What is cost? Is it product attribute?

Comment: Yes its a product attribute

Comment: I want 3 decimal places for "cost" like the "Price", I have used currency_code also but no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code for add column

```
$this->addColumn('cost',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Cost'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
            'type'      => 'price',
            'index' => 'cost',
    ));
```

Comment: yes i tried it by adding 

'type'      => 'price',

but grid goes blank after doing this

Comment: Is it working or having any issue?

Comment: No it goes blank after that

Comment: It is working for me check code if you miss anything

Comment: Sorry!! its not working i tried 5 times but no luck

Comment: Post your code again with updates

Comment: Prashant, I have updated the question

Comment: Hello Prashant It is working fine now Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine with this code now

```
$store = $this->_getStore();
    $this->addColumn('cost',
    array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Cost'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'price',
        'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
        'index' => 'cost',
        ));
```